# Errors when the compiler is trying to build a custom JSP tag based on an Java Bean

Tags: jsp-tags

I am trying to use a custom tag in a jsp page but I get compilation errors so far.
Here is the custom jsp tag code along with the jsp page that is trying to use it.

address.tag

```
<%-- 
    Document   : address
    Created on : Feb 21, 2012, 1:47:19 PM
    Author     : skiabox
--%>

<%@tag description="Address Input Field" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<jsp:useBean id="addressBean" scope="session" class="com.ensode.netbeansbook.AddressBean" />

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<%-- The list of normal or fragment attributes can be specified here: --%>
<%@attribute name="addressType" required="true"%>

<%-- any content can be specified here e.g.: --%>
<table border="0">


        <tr>
            <td>Line 1:&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" size="20" name="${addressType}_line1" id="${addressType}_line1" value="${addressBean.line1}" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Line 2:&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" size="20" name="${addressType}_line2" id="${addressType}_line2" value="${addressBean.line2}" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>City:&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" size="20" name="${addressType}_city" id="${addressType}_city" value="${addressBean.city}" />
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>

            <td>State:&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <select name="${addressType}_state" id="${addressType}_state">

                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="AL"
                        <c:if test="${addressBean.state == 'AL'}">selected</c:if> >
                        Alabama
                    </option>
                    <option value="AK"
                        <c:if test="${addressBean.state == 'AK'}">selected</c:if> >
                        Alaska
                    </option>
                    <option value="AZ"
                        <c:if test="${addressBean.state == 'AZ'}">selected</c:if> >
                        Arizona
                    </option>
                    <option value="AR"
                        <c:if test="${addressBean.state == 'AR'}">selected</c:if> >
                        Arkansas
                    </option>
                    <option value="CA"
                        <c:if test="${addressBean.state == 'CA'}">selected</c:if> >
                        California
                    </option>

                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Zip:&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="${addressType}_zip" id="${addressType}_zip" value="${addressBean.zip}" />
            </td>
        </tr>

</table>
```

index6.jsp

```
<%-- 
    Document   : index6
    Created on : Feb 21, 2012, 3:25:43 PM
    Author     : skiabox
--%>


<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<%@taglib prefix="ct" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/" %>
<%@page import="com.ensode.netbeansbook.AddressBean" %>

<%
    AddressBean addressBean = new AddressBean();
    addressBean.setAddressType("home");
    addressBean.setLine1("123 Tennis Ct");
    addressBean.setCity("Phoenix");
    addressBean.setState("AZ");
    addressBean.setZip("85001");

    session.setAttribute("addressBean", addressBean);
%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <ct:address addressType="home"/>
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 65px;"></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

AddressBean.java

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.ensode.netbeansbook;

/**
 *
 * @author skiabox
 */
public class AddressBean {

    private String addressType;
    private String line1;
    private String line2;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zip;

    public String getAddressType() {
        return addressType;
    }

    public void setAddressType(String addressType) {
        this.addressType = addressType;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getLine1() {
        return line1;
    }

    public void setLine1(String line1) {
        this.line1 = line1;
    }

    public String getLine2() {
        return line2;
    }

    public void setLine2(String line2) {
        this.line2 = line2;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    public void setZip(String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }
}
```

And here is the error log that Netbeans give me when it tries to compile the custom tag :

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation
>   for JSP
>
> PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 48 in the jsp file:
>   /WEB-INF/tags/address.tag PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
>   string:///address_tag.java:215: cannot access
>   javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.ConditionalTagSupport class file for
>   javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.ConditionalTagSupport not found
>
> PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 48 in the jsp file:
>   /WEB-INF/tags/address.tag PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
>   string:///address_tag.java:216: cannot find symbol symbol  : method
>   setPageContext(javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext) location: class
>   org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag
>
> PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 48 in the jsp file:
>   /WEB-INF/tags/address.tag PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
>   string:///address_tag.java:217: cannot find symbol symbol  : method
>   setParent() location: class
>   org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag
>
> PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 48 in the jsp file:
>   /WEB-INF/tags/address.tag PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
>   string:///address_tag.java:219: cannot find symbol symbol  : method
>   doStartTag() location: class
>   org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: string:///address_tag.java:223:
>   cannot find symbol symbol  : method doAfterBody() location: class
>   org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: string:///address_tag.java:228:
>   cannot find symbol symbol  : method doEndTag() location: class
>   org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: string:///address_tag.java:229:
>   reuse(javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag) in
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.TagHandlerPool cannot be applied to
>   (org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag)
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: string:///address_tag.java:232:
>   reuse(javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag) in
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.TagHandlerPool cannot be applied to
>   (org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag)
>
> PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 52 in the jsp file:
>   /WEB-INF/tags/address.tag PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
>   string:///address_tag.java:241: cannot find symbol symbol  : method
>   setPageContext(javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext) location: class
>   org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag
>
> PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 52 in the jsp file:
>   /WEB-INF/tags/address.tag PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
>   string:///address_tag.java:242: cannot find symbol symbol  : method
>   setParent() location: class
>   org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag
>
> PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 52 in the jsp file:
>   /WEB-INF/tags/address.tag PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
>   string:///address_tag.java:244: cannot find symbol symbol  : method
>   doStartTag() location: class
>   org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: string:///address_tag.java:248:
>   cannot find symbol symbol  : method doAfterBody() location: class
>   org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: string:///address_tag.java:253:
>   cannot find symbol symbol  : method doEndTag() location: class
>   org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: string:///address_tag.java:254:
>   reuse(javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag) in
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.TagHandlerPool cannot be applied to
>   (org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag)
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: string:///address_tag.java:257:
>   reuse(javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag) in
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.TagHandlerPool cannot be applied to
>   (org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag)
>
> PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 56 in the jsp file:
>   /WEB-INF/tags/address.tag PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
>   string:///address_tag.java:266: cannot find symbol symbol  : method
>   setPageContext(javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext) location: class
>   org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag
>
> PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 56 in the jsp file:
>   /WEB-INF/tags/address.tag PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
>   string:///address_tag.java:267: cannot find symbol symbol  : method
>   setParent() location: class
>   org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag
>
> PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 56 in the jsp file:
>   /WEB-INF/tags/address.tag PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
>   string:///address_tag.java:269: cannot find symbol symbol  : method
>   doStartTag() location: class
>   org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: string:///address_tag.java:273:
>   cannot find symbol symbol  : method doAfterBody() location: class
>   org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: string:///address_tag.java:278:
>   cannot find symbol symbol  : method doEndTag() location: class
>   org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: string:///address_tag.java:279:
>   reuse(javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag) in
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.TagHandlerPool cannot be applied to
>   (org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag)
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: string:///address_tag.java:282:
>   reuse(javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag) in
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.TagHandlerPool cannot be applied to
>   (org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag)
>
> PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 60 in the jsp file:
>   /WEB-INF/tags/address.tag PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
>   string:///address_tag.java:291: cannot find symbol symbol  : method
>   setPageContext(javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext) location: class
>   org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag
>
> PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 60 in the jsp file:
>   /WEB-INF/tags/address.tag PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
>   string:///address_tag.java:292: cannot find symbol symbol  : method
>   setParent() location: class
>   org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag
>
> PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 60 in the jsp file:
>   /WEB-INF/tags/address.tag PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
>   string:///address_tag.java:294: cannot find symbol symbol  : method
>   doStartTag() location: class
>   org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: string:///address_tag.java:298:
>   cannot find symbol symbol  : method doAfterBody() location: class
>   org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: string:///address_tag.java:303:
>   cannot find symbol symbol  : method doEndTag() location: class
>   org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: string:///address_tag.java:304:
>   reuse(javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag) in
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.TagHandlerPool cannot be applied to
>   (org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag)
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: string:///address_tag.java:307:
>   reuse(javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag) in
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.TagHandlerPool cannot be applied to
>   (org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag)
>
> PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 64 in the jsp file:
>   /WEB-INF/tags/address.tag PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
>   string:///address_tag.java:316: cannot find symbol symbol  : method
>   setPageContext(javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext) location: class
>   org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag
>
> PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 64 in the jsp file:
>   /WEB-INF/tags/address.tag PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
>   string:///address_tag.java:317: cannot find symbol symbol  : method
>   setParent() location: class
>   org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag
>
> PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 64 in the jsp file:
>   /WEB-INF/tags/address.tag PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
>   string:///address_tag.java:319: cannot find symbol symbol  : method
>   doStartTag() location: class
>   org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: string:///address_tag.java:323:
>   cannot find symbol symbol  : method doAfterBody() location: class
>   org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: string:///address_tag.java:328:
>   cannot find symbol symbol  : method doEndTag() location: class
>   org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: string:///address_tag.java:329:
>   reuse(javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag) in
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.TagHandlerPool cannot be applied to
>   (org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag)
>
> PWC6199: Generated servlet error: string:///address_tag.java:332:
>   reuse(javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag) in
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.TagHandlerPool cannot be applied to
>   (org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.IfTag)
>
> /Users/skiabox/NetBeansProjects/simplewebapp2/nbproject/build-impl.xml:612:
>   Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)

As you can see the first error occurs when the code is trying to access addressBean.state
Any ideas on how to fix that or what am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it is very late (over 3 years) to answer this question. I have also had this problem. Apparently the solution is "Clean and Build Project" or press SHIFT+F11 and run again the project.